# how do i update my db data(mongodb) after fixed interval of time using django?

Tags: django, mongodb

My User collection contains data such as

```
    {"user1":"zera",
     "my_status":"active",
     "date_creation" : ISODate("2013-10-01T10:15:52.055Z")
    }
    {"user2":"dfgf",
     "my_status":"noactive",
     "date_creation": ISODate("2013-10-01T08:55:41.212Z")
    }
```

I need to find each user with my_status :"active" and update their my_status after 24 hours from each user's date_creation.
Can anyone suggest a method to do it using django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd write an async task to keep polling the database to check for users with active status. If the user is active, update their status.

For the asynchronous tasks, you can use [python-rq](http://python-rq.org/) but to make things easier there's a django module for python-rq, it's [django-rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq). Also, [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is another popular and good option. There's also a module for Django, you can find it [here](https://github.com/celery/django-celery).

Comment: Is that okay to use apscheduler.scheduler?

Comment: Actually Celery has also a PeriodicTask class => you can run a specific task at regular time intervals and check on your DB entries.